# MSE as a measure of quality of fit for beta regression

Tags: mse, beta-regression

Can MSE be used to measure the quality of fit for beta regression?

Comment: What do you mean by "beta regression"?

Comment: It is a regression model for rates/proportions, in which response is assumed to follow beta distribution. http://www.ime.usp.br/~sferrari/beta.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are mainly interested in getting the expectation of the response E(y) right, (R)MSE or MAE are the obvious candidates for measuring the quality of fit. However, if you are interested in beta regression as a full likelihood model that gives you probabilistic predictions, then proper scoring rules such as the log-likelihood (also called log-score in this literature) or the CRPS (continuous ranked probability score) would be natural candidates.